# How to open a file in another directory in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am in the home directory and i have a file called s0.scm. I cannot copy it to the folder i want since i do not have root capabilities. So, here is what i want to do. In the home directory, i run the following command:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
```

Now i am in this directory. This directory has a program called scheme, and i want to open s0.scm using scheme. I s0.scm was in the same directory with scheme, (/usr/local/bin) then i could have simply written

```
(load "s0.scm")
```

to run it. But since s0.scm is in home directory, i do not know how to do this. Can anyone help me with it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$ cd ~
$ /usr/local/bin/scheme
Welcome to Scheme
> (load "s0.scm")
```

Generally you will want to use the PATH environment variable to easily access programs.  Do

```
$ PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

and then simply

```
$ scheme
```

to start Scheme.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you could also run

```
(load "~/so.scm")
```

because `~` means your home directory.

In general, if you want to load a file located in directory `d`, you can run:

```
(load "path/to/d/file.scm")
```